# How to click through a JDialog?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JDialog that I want to use as an overlay for a game. The dialog simply draws a custom crosshair in the center of my screen, but obviously as fps games tend to center the players cursor I'm unable to use any of my weapons because the JDialog simply focuses..

How could I pass the click events through the JDialog so that the game underneath receives them instead of my JDialog. Right now I have it set to undecorated and it only receives the click events if I click the actual crosshair graphic.

EDIT: I'm created a crosshair for an external game, not my own.

Comment: Why would you use a JDialog for something like that? That's totally backwards.

Comment: I'm inexperienced in this area can you recommend an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

This could help:

```
testDialog.setFocusableWindowState(false);
```

From here:
[Stop newly created dialog from taking focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668010/stop-newly-created-dialog-from-taking-focus)

Besides that, maybe it is better for you to get the Graphics object of the frame in behind and use the graphics to draw the crosshair directly.

E.g.

```
Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
g.setColor(CROSSHAIR_COLOR);
g.drawLine(.....); // Vertical Line
g.drawLine(.....); // Horizontal Line
```

Comment: I'm still unable to click through it, my mouse cursor becomes visible over it and when I click nothing happens on the underlying game, also that is currently how I'm drawing the crosshair.

Comment: Then why do you need the Dialog? Maybe you can just remove it? For your question: Another option is you catch the mouseevent in the dialog. And the call something like panel.myOnClickMethod(clickX + dialogOffset, clickY + dialogOffset)

Comment: I need the dialog to get a graphics object to draw onto.

Comment: Ok, then the interesting question is, how is your actual game drawn? Because any panel or frame or in general component in swing will have the getGraphics() method.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be achievable using JNA and the following code;

```
private static void setTransparent(Component w) {
    WinDef.HWND hwnd = getHWnd(w);
    int wl = User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowLong(hwnd, WinUser.GWL_EXSTYLE);
    wl = wl | WinUser.WS_EX_LAYERED | WinUser.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
    User32.INSTANCE.SetWindowLong(hwnd, WinUser.GWL_EXSTYLE, wl);
}

/**
 * Get the window handle from the OS
 */
private static HWND getHWnd(Component w) {
    HWND hwnd = new HWND();
    hwnd.setPointer(Native.getComponentPointer(w));
    return hwnd;
}
```